# Игра подсчитывание монет, что можно улучшить?

Tags: python, инспекция-кода

Создайте игру, которая просит пользователя ввести не­обходимое количество монет, чтобы получился ровно один рубль. Программа должна предложить пользователю ввести количество монет достоинством и 5, 10, 50 копеек. Если итоговое значение введенных монет равно одному рублю, то программа должна
поздравить пользователя с выигрышем. В противном случае программа должна вывести сообщение, говорящее о том, была ли введенная сумма больше или меньше одного рубля. Подумайте о варианте игры, где вместо рубля используется доллар и разменные монеты: пенс, пятицентовик, десятицентовик и четвертак.

Написал вот такой вот код, все работает, но мне интересно какие есть варианты по его улучшению.

```
coin_5 = int(input("Введите коины по 5 копеек: "))
coin_10 = int(input("Введите коины по 10 копеек: "))
coin_50 = int(input("Введите коины по 50 копеек: "))
ruble = (coin_5 * 0.05) + (coin_10 * 0.10) + (coin_50 * 0.50)
print("У вас получилось: ", + ruble)
if ruble == 1:
print("Поздравляем, вы выиграли")
elif ruble > 1:
print("Сумма слишком большая")
elif ruble < 1:
print("Сумма слишком мала.")
```

Comment: Попробуйте ввести `24`, `-2`, `0` и добро пожаловать в волшебный мир чисел с плавающей точкой

Comment: Заменить дробные числа целыми. Добавить проверку на положительность. Добавить возможность ввести все числа в одну строку.

Answer (score 0):

первое что приходит на ум... и можно попробовать улучшить это:

1. добавить некоторые проверки входных данных (в виде функции, которая будет ожидать ввода корректных данных), чтобы исключить возможные ошибки
2. добавить константы
3. использовать форматированный вывод результата для вывода вещественных чисел, с заданным кол. знаков после запятой...

Пример:

```
COIN_5_VALUE = 0.05
COIN_10_VALUE = 0.10
COIN_50_VALUE = 0.50

def get_valid_input(prompt):
    while True:
        try:
            value = int(input(prompt))
            if value >= 0:
                return value
            print("Введите положительное число.")
        except ValueError:
            print("Введите целое число.")

coin_5 = get_valid_input("Введите коины по 5 копеек: ")
coin_10 = get_valid_input("Введите коины по 10 копеек: ")
coin_50 = get_valid_input("Введите коины по 50 копеек: ")

ruble = (coin_5 * COIN_5_VALUE) + (coin_10 * COIN_10_VALUE) + (coin_50 * COIN_50_VALUE)

print("У вас получилось: {:.2f} рублей".format(ruble))

if ruble == 1:
    print("Поздравляем, вы выиграли")
elif ruble > 1:
    print("Сумма слишком большая")
else:
    print("Сумма слишком мала.")
```